# Disaggregate image html on webpage

Tags: html

I want to get a picture of a motorcycle, by passing the mouse above tell me which parts it is (wheel, casing, handlebar, brakes ...) but I do not know how to do it. I searched but I do not know where to start. It's to put it on my website.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the map tag to create regions in the image and create on hover actions for each region. [See an example here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_map.asp)

Comment: There are online tools which can help you create these regions, but you'll probably need some JS to create the hover actions. You might be able to set a title on the map elements and get the tooltip popup when you hover mouse over it

Comment: An image map will work, but it's a fairly dated technology, and it won't allow OP to customize much. I'd recommend using a newer technology such as SVG or canvas tag -- perhaps check out libraries such as [D3.js](https://d3js.org/).